# Android: Share Image intent not working with Facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

Hi I have the following code to share an image:

```
// Share
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "myGoal.jpg");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

It works to share the image to Dropbox but if I pick the Facebook option, I get Facebook's status update dialog with no image attached and if I try to update my status with 'Test' it doesn't work. No errors. Just not working.

I know it's not the image because it uploads to my Dropbox properly and I can pull up the image and look at it.

Do I have to attach the image to the intent differently for it to work with Facebook?

Any ideas? I'm debugging on a physical device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured out the problem.

I was saving the picture to internal storage with getFilesDir() which put the picture into my apps sandbox and made inaccessible to the other apps.

I replaced my code with the following:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                "/MyApp/";

File dir = new File(file_path);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "myPic.png");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

fOut.flush();
fOut.close();

// Share
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/png");

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Image");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Is your EXTRA_TEXT actually appearing in your facebook post? As far as I tall it is never consumed by the Activity responding to the Facebook ACTION_SEND Intent.

Comment: In case it helps somebody, I think what actually made it work was changing from `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));` to `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));`

Cheers!

Comment: Actually I think it's probably a combination of both the location change and the way to pass the extra. At least I always had the external path but only worked with `Uri.fromFile`

Comment: What is `screenshot` in your code? How to initialize it?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad If I remember right, screenshot is a Bitmap object. If you follow the code, you see that I create a File object and I push the bitmap data to it in PNG format. Then that same file gets used as part of the Intent.

Comment: Any way to `Intent.ACTION_SEND` file stored in app's internal storage `getFilesDir()`?

Answer (score 0):

What i have done to post image on facebook is instead of passing it directly i create a function and write it like this :

```
 private void ShareWall(String message) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                // share msg
        parameters.putString("message", message);
                // shre image which you have define above
        parameters.putString("picture", postImage);

        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("response: ", response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")) {
                response.equals("");
                showToast("No Response.");

            } else {
                showToast("Message has been posted to your walll!.");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Message failed to posdt on wall.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can still share images (but not text) from your app to Facebook even if you are not using the Facebook SDK.

Just make sure that you use Uri.fromFile instead of Uri.parse and it will work:

DO NOT USE:
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(pathToFile));

USE:
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToFile)));

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using external file write:

```
Drawable mDrawable = myImageView1.getDrawable();
Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Image I want to share", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

In this case, my image comes from an ImageView myImageView.